# how to redirect second last page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

In my application I need to save state of an URL, in which I need to store request path of the 2nd to last request. I know `request.reffer` returns last page `URL` but I need the 2nd to last page URL, how can I achieve this without `routes` modification and without any `params`? Is it possible to achieve that?

Scenario:

Suppose I have some authentication page for check out now.

1. The user can access the product page without authentication.
2. When the user wants to buy product he needs to login or signup.
3. With login I can achieve redirect back to product path
4. But the signup link is available on the signing page so `request.reffer` will return sign in path after signup.

How can I then redirect to the correct (product) page?

Any good suggestion are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly: you'd like a link to direct the user to, not the previously viewed page, but the page before that. You can achieve this simply with some javascript:

```
<%= link_to "Double Back", "javascript:history.go(-2);" %>
```

What this does is use the browser's history to jump two URLs back in time. It is equivalent to clicking the back button on your browser twice.

I recently solved a similar problem with a page that sometimes directs to itself after submitting a form. When this happened, the `:back` button would become useless because the last page the user was on was the same page. I got around it using the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Back", "javascript: if (document.referrer == '#{request.original_url}'){history.go(-2);} else {history.go(-1);}" %>
```

This says "if the previous page is this same page, jump back two pages, else, jump back to the previous page"

#### UPDATE:

Reading your question again, it sounds like maybe you are trying to get the previous previous page inside Rails for use in a redirect? If thats the case the solution above won't work, but you could use The Flash to store the previous page and carry it forward to the next page (where it would be the previous previous page) and then access it and use it for a redirect. The Flash is explained in the Rails guides here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

I imagine the solution would look something like:

```
first controller action
  flash[:previous_page] = "#{request.original_url}"
end

second controller action
  redirect_to flash[:previous_page]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rails session. Whenever a user visit a product page you should save the product id in session. After login you can redirect to the product page stored in session which is always the latest viewed product.